# My bottle is leaking CO2 Idk if it is the bottle or the cap

Tags: beer

I am new at brewing, and i am having some problems trying to keep my beer carbonated. I am using twist off 12oz bottles with regular crown caps. can somebody please tell me if there is a certain specific kind of cap for twist off bottles or if there is a certain type of bottle capper for the twist off bottle? thanks, and your help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the twist-off bottles, not the caps or the capper.  You need to use pop-top bottles.

Comment: twist offs don't work with crown caps, if you need bottles, ask your local bar or friends for a bunch of Pop top bottles, or buy from your local home brew shop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, is there a specific type of caps that has to be used with twist- off bottles?

Comment: Not at the homebrewing level.